Fix corrupted line endings in directory recursively in text files only (Linux, Mac, or Windows)
I've got a directory tree full of both text and binary files, some with Unix line endings (LF/\n), some with Windows line endings (CRLF/\r\n) and some with corrupted line endings of the form CRCR+LF/\r\r+\n (that is, LF preceded by more than one CR). I cannot disambiguate text and binary files by extension. Nor are all of the text files in the same encoding (though they are supposed to be). Most are UTF-8, but some are UTF-16 with a BOM, and some appear to be Latin-1. Preserving the encodings is not necessary, but preserving the non-line ending contents is.
I want to leave all of the binary files and Unix-ending text files alone, and I want to turn all of the CRCR+LF files into CRLF files. I do not want to turn everything into Unix-ending files, but I will if I have to.
Finally, I suspect that there is a stray CR (Classic Mac line ending) by itself in some of the files that have been corrupted. I want to remove this if it exists.
I can do this on Mac or Windows, however my previous attempts to fix the line endings with Powershell did not work, although it did bring the number of extra CRs down to just 1. To try to keep this problem under control, I've been find-and-replacing 0d0d0a with 0d0a in a hex editor repeatedly when I find one of these files, but this is getting old fast.
Edit: I have Perforce available which tracks the filetype (text or binary) accurately enough.

To normalise line endings
To simply convert all the line endings in a file to the right one for a specific platform, dos2unix and unix2dos are the standard tools for this, which you can get in a Unix-like environment such as WSL2, or something like Cygwin (what I personally use).
dos2unix will convert all line endings to Windows line endings (CRLF), and unix2dos will convert all line endings to Unix line endings (LF). For example, to convert all files in the directory to Windows line endings:
unix2dos *.*

Or just to convert a particular file:
unix2dos file.txt


To fix corrupted line endings
To fix the rare case of line endings that have become corrupted such as in the OP's case, a search-and-replace is the right idea, but instead of manually using a GUI binary editor the right tool to use would be a shell tool that allows you to do it programatically. sed is generally the go-to Unix tool for a search-and-replace. Additonally, you don't need to work with hex if you're only editing text files as stated in the OP.
To replace the corrupted line endings \r\r\n with \r\n in all files in the current directory, backup the entire directory, do a cd /path/to/directory to make sure you're in the same directory as the files.
Then either run the following command on WSL, Cygwin or similar:
sed -i 's/\r\r\n/\r\n/gi; s/\n$//' file.txt

Or the following command on Mac:
gsed -i "" 's/\r\r\n/\r\n/gi; s/\n$//' file.txt


I'm not asking about converting line endings, I'm asking about fixing non-standard line endings.

@icodestuff My bad, I didn't read the question properly, but now that I have I'm a little more confused as to why you're using a binary editor to do this when you said you only want to work on text files with corrupted Windows line endings. Either way the edit should do what you want.

Better, but won't this also edit the binary files that have \r\r\n coincidentally? I may be working with text, but I need to work around the binary files there too, and I can't disambiguate between them by extension. I also want to remove any solo \rs as well, if they exist. And is sed UTF-16 aware?

@icodestuff Good point, you probably won't have a choice except to do each file one at a time, which is still a hell of a lot faster than doing each linebreak manually like you were before. I'm not sure about UTF-16 - try it and see whether it works. As for removing \r I would do that in a separate call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854568/how-to-remove-r-character-with-sed.

@icodestuff you could batch grep for candidate files and tag them by using a custom extension; examine this shortlist of tagged files manually for false positives and remove the custom extension for those false positives; batch the remainder as mentioned in this answer and automagically untag them as it processes them

@HashimAziz I'm not doing it one linebreak at a time; I'm already doing it one file at a time, just running the Replace All multiple times until it stops finding matches. Eg if I have a file with both CRCRLFs and CRCRCRLFs the first Replace All fixes the first example (making it CRLF), and turns the second example into the first example (CRCRLF), so I need to run it twice on the same file to get rid of both.
